# Migration from XML to Annotation configuration in Hibernate 4.2

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have always used hibernate.cfg.xml to configure Hibernate. For various reasons I need to move all the configuration to Java and I have problem with mapping entities.

Previously in XML my mappings looked like this:

```
<mapping class="com.mycompany.enitites.Test" />
```

Everything is annotation driven, so I did not need to specify anything else.

Now that I configure everything using Hibernate's `Configuration.class`, how to add the mappings? I tried `configuration.addClass(Test.class)` but this throws an error that file `test.hbm.xml` does not exist. And I don't want to use it, I want Hibernate to read the mappings from annotations.

EDIT: I tried `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Test.class)` but this throws `relation "test" does not exist` on the first encountered query that involved `Test.class` entity.

Answer (score 0):

I made grammar mistake in the following line:

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
```

Which preventing Hibernate from creating tables in startup and thus not finding them...